How to bind gnus-summary-mail-other-window without starting gnus?
$ emacs
C-h k C-x m
C-x m runs the command compose-mail
$ emacs -f gnus
C-h k C-x m
C-x m runs the command gnus-summary-mail-other-window

So how do I achieve the second binding, without the expense of
starting gnus each session, since I don't necessarily use C-x m or gnus
every day?

I would try (keymap-set ctl-x-map "m" #'gnus-summary-mail-other-window) but I don't really understand the point of the question: if there is no gnus around, why do you want to use this function? What's wrong with the default compose-mail?

Thanks but that ran into a "commandp" error. Also I want all guns features when composing a mail. OK, I solved it below.

(defun dan-gnus-mess () "Bind even without starting gnus first!"
       (interactive)
       (progn(gnus)(gnus-summary-mail-other-window)))
(keymap-set ctl-x-map "m" #'dan-gnus-mess)


We can bind without needing to start gnus first to just do the bind.
We get all gnus features enabled when composing a mail, instead of the default fewer features.

